# Cannot update github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I pushed some changes on my master branch, then I want those changes to also be pushed on my gh-pages branch, so I run these commands:

```
git checkout gh-pages
git rebase master
git push origin gh-pages
```

but I always get these errors:

```
! [rejected]        gh-pages -> gh-pages (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How do I update github pages website?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your local repository is not up to date with remote repository. You need to pull the changes first and then push again.
You can follow following steps:

```
git pull origin gh-pages
```

See if there are any merge conflicts and resolve them. And then run

```
git push origin gh-pages
```